# Inconsistent results between R2Cuba and integrate()

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I have experienced an inconsistent results from integrate() and suave() from package "R2Cuba" when computing a two-fold integration.

[image]

where

[image]

A similar question related to this topic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340846/2-fold-repeated-integral-in-r/40340894#40340894), let's set f(x)=6*sin(x) and g(x)=1 and the upper time T=3.

The following code use integrate() and suave() to compute the objective 2-fold integral:

```
library(R2Cuba)

integrand = function(x){6*sin(x)}

phi = function(x){integrate(integrand,lower=x,upper = 3)[["value"]]^2}

NDIM=1
NCOMP=1

phicuba= function(x){suave(NDIM,NCOMP,integrand,lower=x,upper=3)$value^2}

foldintegral = integrate(Vectorize(phi),lower = 0,upper = 3)

foldintegralcuba = suave(NDIM,NCOMP,phicuba,lower = 0,upper = 3)
```

The results:

```
> foldintegral
167.3934 with absolute error < 1.9e-12
> foldintegralcuba
integral: 6.365749 (+-0.0057)
nregions: 8; number of evaluations:  10000; probability:  1
```

which is not consistent. However, if we only compare `phi` and `phicuba`

```
> phi(2)
[1] 11.85476
> phicuba(2)
Iteration 1:  1000 integrand evaluations so far
[1] 3.44367 +- 0.0429822    chisq 0 (0 df)
Iteration 2:  2000 integrand evaluations so far
[1] 3.4436 +- 0.00866171    chisq 0.00513973 (2 df)
Iteration 3:  3000 integrand evaluations so far
[1] 3.44181 +- 0.00386046   chisq 5.38913 (5 df)
Iteration 4:  4000 integrand evaluations so far
[1] 3.44283 +- 0.00206345   chisq 23.0816 (8 df)
[1] 11.85309
```

We got a result that can be seen as consistent. Moreover, if we use replace the integrand inside `suave()`

```
> suave(NDIM,NCOMP,phi,lower = 0,upper = 3)
Iteration 1:  1000 integrand evaluations so far
[1] 167.426 +- 4.91983      chisq 0 (0 df)
Iteration 2:  2000 integrand evaluations so far
[1] 167.315 +- 0.771248     chisq 0.00208764 (2 df)
Iteration 3:  3000 integrand evaluations so far
[1] 167.357 +- 0.432941     chisq 5.50239 (5 df)
Iteration 4:  4000 integrand evaluations so far
[1] 167.362 +- 0.129012     chisq 5.51661 (8 df)
integral: 167.3621 (+-0.13)
nregions: 4; number of evaluations:  4000; probability:  0.2988006
```

We still have consistent result.

I wish I can use the suave() since it is much faster when dealing with complicated integral, but why this inconsistent exists?

=========================UPDATE===============================

It seems it is because the algorithm used in suave(), [From the Cuba Documentation](http://www.feynarts.de/cuba/), suave use globally adaptive subdivision  + importance sampling. If change suave() to cuhre(), which only use globally adaptive subdivision, everything should be consistent.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is because the algorithm used in suave(), From the Cuba Documentation, suave use globally adaptive subdivision + importance sampling. If change suave() to cuhre(), which only use globally adaptive subdivision, everything should be consistent.